# Not allowed to view the pages after upgrade

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I have a website where the civicrm plugin stopped working and developed an error. I have since copied the site onto another hosting account I have and have been following these upgrade steps (https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+WordPress#UpgradingCiviCRMforWordPress-verify_settings) to upgrade the plugin (as it's been a year and a half anyways). I've gotten to step 4 but when visiting the link it says

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

I saw in the upgrade steps it mentioned if you have issues to activate the plugin in wp-admin/plugins.php but I've never done it that way. Is there a chance anyone can let me know if "activating" it via plugins.php file may work and how might I do that? If it isn't that (as I didn't deactivate the plugin before upgrade) why my Administrator account wouldn't have access to this page? of the civi crm dashboard in wordpress?

I had tried deactivating all the plugins via the wordpress backend but then I was shut out of my site (os there a way with this plugins.php file to activate them all again or do I have to delete and re-do all the steps again of getting another backup and upgrading civi crm?).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution ?

Comment: I did not. Still working on it. Did you find a solution by chance?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem, but found the answer on this page:

[WordPress - Problems trying to go back to CiviCRM 4.7.17 from 4.7.19](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18623/wordpress-problems-trying-to-go-back-to-civicrm-4-7-17-from-4-7-19)

I had previously installed CiviCRM but wanted to remove it and start from scratch, but I hadn't deleted the civicrm folder in /wp-content/uploads/