# WordPress - Problems trying to go back to CiviCRM 4.7.17 from 4.7.19

Tags: wordpress, installation, 4.7

I've been having [problems](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18560/cant-edit-scheduled-job-page-not-formatted-api-call-missing) trying to get CiviCRM 4.7.19 working. So I thought I'd try going back to CiviCRM 4.7.17, which I had managed to get working pretty well on another site. I deactivated and deleted CiviCRM 4.7.19, deleted and recreated the MySQL database, and uploaded, extracted and activated CiviCRM 4.7.17.

When I go to Settings on the WordPress dashboard, I don't see "CiviCRM Installer".

When I try http://<my_wordpress_home>/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install

I get "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."  (Even though I am logged in as a WordPress administrator in another tab.)

I'm pretty new to CiviCRM and not sure where to go from here. Thanks for any tips you can provide.

WordPress 4.7.4 running on Linux.

http://connectionpracticecoach.com

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions?  The account running the webserver software has to be able to read all the civi files and write to some directories.

Answer (score 1):

The civicrm directory under wp-content/uploads was not deleted when I deleted CiviCRM through the WordPress plugins interface. I deleted that manually using cPanel, and the install went normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you unpacked the zip file in /wp-content/plugins as user root and that whole directory tree is owned by www-data or a similar user, that would be the problem.

Try ls -l one level back in the directory, see what username owns the files. If it's www-data, this incantation would fix it:

chmod -R www-data ./plugins

chgrp -R www-data ./plugins